# Flickering when hovering on an Avatar component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the MUI library, I have a Card component and an Avatar component inside a Grid Item. When you hover over the avatar, the Card component should popup, but it seems to be flickering when hovering over the avatar. Not entirely sure if this has to do with me not providing the correct keys to the components, or I need to apply some css styles on one component to avoid the flickering action. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import { Avatar, Card, CardContent, Divider, Grid, List, ListItem, ListItemText, Paper, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { FunctionComponent, ReactElement, useState } from 'react';

export const People: FunctionComponent = (): ReactElement => {
  const [hoveredEmployee, setHoveredEmployee] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleMouseOver = (employeeName: string): void => {
    setHoveredEmployee(employeeName);
  };

  const handleMouseOut = (): void => {
    setHoveredEmployee(null);
  };
  const employeeDetailsMapped = {sammy: {loginName: 'smy', fullName: 'sammy chung'}}

  const groupedUsers: Record<string, string[]> = {};

  employeeDetails.forEach((item) => {
    const firstLetter = item.loginName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

    if (!groupedUsers[firstLetter]) {
      groupedUsers[firstLetter] = [item.loginName];
    } else {
      groupedUsers[firstLetter].push(item.loginName);
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Paper elevation={2} sx={{ p: 3, my: 2, width: '100%', overflowY: 'auto', maxHeight: 600 }}>
          {Object.entries(groupedUsers).map(([letter, names]) => (
            <Grid item key={letter} sx={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #ddd' }}>
              <h3>{letter}</h3>
              <>
                {names.map((name: string) => (
                  <div key={name} style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: 10 }}>
                    <Avatar
                      variant='rounded'
                      alt={`Photo of ${employeeDetailsMapped[name].loginName}`}
                      src={`...`}
                      sx={{ height: 80, width: 80, mr: 2 }}
                      onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
                      onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
                    />
                    {hoveredEmployee === name && (
                      <Card
                        elevation={3}
                        style={{ padding: 16 }}
                        sx={{
                          height: 'auto',
                          width: '480px',
                          ':hover': {
                            boxShadow: 20,
                          },
                        }}>
                        <CardContent key={name}>
                          <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignContent: 'center' }}>
                            <Avatar
                              variant='rounded'
                              alt={`Badge photo for ${employeeDetailsMapped[name].loginName}`}
                              src={`...`}
                              sx={{ height: 130, width: 130 }}
                            />
                            <Typography variant='h5' fontWeight={1} marginTop={6} marginLeft={10}>
                              {employeeDetailsMapped[name].fullName}
                            </Typography>
                          </div>

                        </CardContent>
                      </Card>
                    )}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try using `onMouseEnter={handleMouseOver}` instead of `onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}`. Unlike `onMouseOver`,  `onMouseEnter`  does not fire again if the mouse enters a child element within the parent element.

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but it did not work.

Comment: Figured it out, I edited the code.

Comment: Great! On StackOveflow, if you manage to fix your problem, you should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I've put an answer to the question asked. If you guys want to see the tooltip method as well, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the code above using the original code. A more concise way I ended up writing this code was to not use the useState hook on hover, but used MUI's Tooltip component. The trick is to place your component code inside the title property of the Tooltip component. The width of the tooltip can be adjusted as well, so I removed the tooltip container thats provided, and used a Card component for my usecase.